# How do I set the Visible attribute in an ItemTemplate?

Tags: asp.net-2.0, templatefield

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Audio">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="playImage" runat="server"
            ImageUrl="~/images/nextpg.gif"
            Visible='<%# (Eval("available")=="Y") ? true : false %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In my query I am returning the "available" column which is populated with a letter of Y or N. For some reason the evaluation of this expression is never true. If I change it to `!=` instead of `==` it will always be true. That leads me to believe the `Eval("available")=="Y"` is simply not evaluating as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much messing around, this finally worked:

```
<%# ((String)Eval("available")).Equals("Y") ? true : false %>
```

The issue seems to be that you can't use `==` but instead you must use the `String.Equals()` method. I'm not sure *why* but that's just the way it is.